# How do I fix layout issues with constraints in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I used the following constraints to build one screen for my app. However the icon buttons get messed up in different screen sizes (screenshots below). Is there a way to rectify this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Colin, did you get your solution or still not

Comment: Hi Raj! I didn't seem to get a solution after following some of the suggestions below.

Comment: Colin, did any of the followup suggestions work for you? (I included a sample in mine)

Answer (score 0):

1- Give equal heights and equal widths to all 4 boxes.

2 - For first one-> leading, top, 
  - For second one(travel and place)-> horizontal spacing to 1st one,leading and top
  - For third one(activity)-> vertical spacing with 1st one ,horizontal to utilities and leading 
  - For fourth one-> trailing , vertical spacing to 2nd one and horizontal spacing to activity

Comment: Thanks Anurag! However, I didn't managed to get the issue resolved...
Here's a link to what I saw in simulator:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4HWJ5QOX-QEalRCdlEtUXU0RGc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I managed to fix the problem by adding the 'aspect ratio' constraint. I also removed equal heights since it is redundant after fixing aspect ratio. However, the text (Food, Attractions, etc.) are actually labels. Is there any way to align them to the top left of each box? I try applying the same concept used for the boxes, to align the labels but they seem to be cut off and alignment isn't very good: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4HWJ5QOX-QEeUxHM0NTVkp4eTA/view

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is:

- Set a proportional size (width and height) to the first button, maybe 40% of the container.
- Then for the other 3 buttons, you can set them to the same size as the first.
- Add some space between them.
- And thats it.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Take two views as two rows

2 - Let for first view (row), add two subviews , give the width of first equal to width of superview and multiplier 0.5 , let the second view align leading to first view trailing and width equal to first view

3 - add the button as subview in each view with top , right , bottom and left spacing as desired. Repeat the same for 2nd button in 2nd view.

4 - Repeat the above steps for row 2 view

hope this helps

Comment: Hi @user2990898, may I know what do you mean by a superview? And how does the multiplier work?

Comment: superview would be the containing view. Consider the top 2 food and travel button only. first add a view to uiviewcontroller view and then add these two buttons as subview in that view.

Answer (score 0):

These are actually pretty straightforward when you think about how all the views are supposed to relate to each other. I made a [demo storyboard](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o3c0s43jykgsb0r/SO_Solution-20160313.storyboard?dl=0) to show you how I'd wire it up. The key things:

- Each box has a 1:1 aspect ratio.
- Boxes in a row have equal widths to each other
- Each box is constrained on both sides to the edge of the view or each other
- The icon's height is set to a % of the box's height
- The labels are pinned to the top, right, and left of the box

[image: iPhone4S][image: iPhone 7 Plus]

Obviously you'll want to adjust your styling as appropriate, but that should get you the effect you want.